# Why does a Pointer need address-of operator in its argument to modify the value of a structure member?

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

Why did the pointer "precord" (in code sample 1) needed an address-of operator to change the value in structure member?

```
//Code Sample 1

#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{int a;};

void input(struct student *);

void main() {
  struct student age;
  printf("Enter Your Age\n");
  input(&age);
  printf("%d",age.a);
}

void input(struct student *precord) {
  scanf("%d",&precord->a);
}
```

While pointer successfully managed to change the value of another variable without address-of operator in Code Sample 2.

```
//Code Sample 2
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int *);
void main() {
  int age;
  printf("Enter Your Age\n");
  input(&age);
  printf("%d",age);
}

void input(int *precord) {
  scanf("%d",precord);
}
```

Comment: 'precord->age' - nope. Function calls can not modify their arguments.

Comment: To call `input` from main you need to declare it first.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n] %d",precord->name,&precord->age);`

Comment: This is another example of the confusion caused by the inexplicable decision to allow arrays to be passed by addess without needing an '&' address operator.

Comment: 'is not executing i think' - debugger!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the address of the integer you want to read in to `scanf()`.

```
scanf("%[^\n] %d", precord->name, &(precord->age));
```

This will allow the user to type in the value for `name`, hit `RETURN` and then type in the value for `age` and hit `RETURN`.

If you want the user to type in both `name` and `age` on the same line, separated by a space, and `name` is not to include any spaces, you can do

```
scanf("%[^ \n] %d", precord->name, &(precord->age));
```

to have `scanf()` stop reading characters for `name` when it hits a space.

Answer (score 1):

When I built your program, I get the following warnings, which cover what was said in the comments:

```
sc.c: In function ‘main’:
sc.c:15:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘input’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   input(&record);
   ^
sc.c: At top level:
sc.c:19:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘input’
 void input(struct student *precord)
      ^
sc.c:15:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘input’ was here
   input(&record);
   ^
sc.c: In function ‘input’:
sc.c:22:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    scanf("%[^\n] %d",precord->name,precord->age);
          ^
```

There is one more problem, namely that %[^\n] eats up the whole line, so that entering for example "Mike 25" makes "Mike 25" be the name, and then it waits for the age on the next line.

I recommend against ever using 'scanf'. Read lines into a string instead, and then use 'sscanf', and always check the result so you get the number of matched values that you expect.

Comment: are you suggesting to use sscanf always instead of scanf %[^\n] ?

Comment: I meant that 'sscanf' gives you better control over what was input than 'scanf'. I see now that the problem was fixed by adding a blank, whether using 'scanf' or not, in Stephen Docy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `scanf` function, we have to provide the address of the `variable`. But in your case for the **first argument**, you are providing the `base address of the array but for the second argument`, you are dereferencing the structure member age through the pointer. you have to provide the address of the variable age.  Update your `scanf` arguments as follows:

---

```
scanf("%[^\n] %d",precord->name,precord->age);
```

I will print the inputs.

Comment: Use:scanf("%[^\n] %d",precord->name, &precord->age);